# Problemas con la virtualizacion en VMware

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtualización, vmware

tengo un problema a la hora de virtualizar en vmware, a partir de ahí me surgieron varias dudas, acabo de descargar e instalar VMware, pero a la hora de crear una máquina virtual e intentar instalar kali linux, primeramente me apareció el siguiente error:

this kernel requires an x86-64 cpu but only detected an i686 cpu vmware

Pero, esto sucedió porque no tenía bien configurada la máquina virtual, pero al hacerlo bien, obtuve un error parecido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me doy cuenta que el error es porque tengo que entrar a la BIOS para activar la virtualización, pero al investigar me surgió una duda, yo tengo como sistema operativo Windows 7 Home Basic, pero no se exactamente si puedo virtualizar en este sistema operativo, ya que leí por ahí que no se puede, por eso quiero saber si esa información es verídica y si no lo es, pues como puedo activar las opciones de virtualización para mi sistema operativo, por cierto mi PC es de 64 bits y mi sistema operativo igual, tengo 4GB de RAM y 2 procesadores, al crear y configurar la máquina virtual yo le di 2GB de RAM y en otros casos 1GB, como procesadores yo le puse 1 procesador.
Por su atención gracias, ojala y puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: tu problema esta relacionada al manejo de aplicaciones en el sistema operativo, y no a algo relacionado a los objetivos del sitio (Desarrollo y programación).

Answer (score 1):

A mi siempre que me sucede eso, eso por lo que dices, que en la bios no esta activo la opcion de virtuallizacion.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: pero es posible activar la virtualización en windows 7 home basic?